# Ubuntu: deb control file has no build-depends, where do they come from then?

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I have a deb file whose control file does not contain any build-depends line, but still the package has build-dependencies. So where do they come from? I can't figure it out.

This is the deb file: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/xUbuntu_14.10/i386/owncloud-client_2.0.0-1_i386.deb
You can see that the control file only has Depends, no build-depends.

But
    apt-rdepends --build-depends --follow=DEPENDS owncloud-client
shows build-dependencies:
    owncloud-client
      Build-Depends: cmake
      Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)
      Build-Depends: kdelibs5-dev
      Build-Depends: libneon27-gnutls-dev
      Build-Depends: libocsync-dev (>= 0.91.4)
      Build-Depends: libqt4-dev
and so on.

Also 
    sudo apt-get build-dep owncloud-client
installs those dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The binary package doesn't have build dependencies (any longer), because it was already built. The source package certainly has them; and when you download the source package, you should find that the actual `debian/control` file in there *does* contain a Build-Depends stanza.

A typical control file has a source package declaration followed by one or more binary package declarations. Something like this:

```
Source: foo
Build-depends: libbar-dev, baz

Package: foo-server
Depends: libbar

Package: foo-client
Depends: python
```

So to build foo-server and foo-client, you need the foo source package and *its* build dependencies; but the resulting binary packages are just the deliverables, and don't have their own individual build dependencies.

Compare also the entry in http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/xUbuntu_14.10/Sources against the one in http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/xUbuntu_14.10/Packages (this is the server I got redirected to from your .deb package link).

Comment: Thanks a lot! http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_14.04/Sources does not mention libocsync-dev but apt-rdepends lists it as a direct build dependency (see above). How is that possible?

Comment: Every binary package is supposed to have an associated source package, if there is a "Source:" field in the binary package's control data then it specifies the associated source package. Otherwise the associated source package is assumed to be the one with the same name and version as the binary package.